# Ajax is not receiving data from python

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type:"get",
    url:"https://firststep-2016.appspot.com/getLatLng",
    dataType: "json",
    cache:false,
    success:function(latLng){
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),{
        zoom: 11,
        center:latLng[0]
        });     

        $.each(latLng,function(i,value){
            new google.maps.Marker({
            position: value,
            map: map
            }); 
        });
    }
});
setTimeout("loadUser()",5000);
```

This is python

```
class getLatLng(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    db = connect_to_cloudsql()
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""select latitude,longitude from User;""")

    dic={}
    array_list=[]
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        dic['lat']=float(row[0])
        dic['lng']=float(row[1])
        array_list.append(dic.copy())

    latLng=json.dumps(array_list)
    db.close()

    return latLng
```

I want to show my location on Google map in real time. So I use AJAX to get the position every 5 seconds. But the map does not come up. and occur error.

> jquery-2.2.1.min.js:4 GET
>   https://firststep-2016.appspot.com/getLatLng?_=1505302511778 500 ()

[image]

Comment: Is that all your code? Where is `loadUser()` defined? Are you sure the ajax call is _being made_ in the first place?

Comment: sorry. i upload now

Comment: The called URL `https://firststep-2016.appspot.com/getLatLng` returns `internal server error`. Add a error handler to your Ajax call : `error : function(err){ console.log(err) }`

Comment: Did you found any error in web console ?

Comment: message from web console.  -> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable